# How can i create a custom tabbar?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Hello everyone i am trying to create a tabbar in IOS. Firstly the tabbar will have 3 items. And the 3 items images width are different. The first 2 tabbar are 75 pixels each and the 3rd on is 170 pixels.( and each of them will have custom images )

[image]
Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of third party library are available so you can use one of them.

For the starting point you can refere [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar).

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Comment: If it's help to you then just accept my answer so that i will help to other also and if possible the +1 to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the image of background gray colour image to tabbar background image

```
tabBarCntrl.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"graybackground.png"];
```

set the your desired frames to a,b,c imageviews.And set the red colour images to those imageviews.

```
aImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 420, 50, 50)];

bImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95, 420,50, 43)];

cImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(175, 420, 100, 50)];



aImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];

bImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];

cImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"c.png"];
```

subview the three images to tabbarcontroller

```
[tabBarCntrl.view addSubview:customersImageView];
[tabBarCntrl.view addSubview:invoicesImageView];
[tabBarCntrl.view addSubview:dashboardImageView];

[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarCntrl.view];
```

Comment: Wellcome @veereef. If you succeed with my answer(post) accept this answer.